# How can I toggle the headphone jack in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, headphones, headphone-jack

I have a keyboard that has a headphone jack on it. In order to use it, the audio cable must be plugged into the back of the computer. If I hook that up, the headphone jack on the keyboard works great, but if I don't want to use the headphones, I have to unplug it from the back of my computer.

**Is there a way to easily toggle whether I want to use the headphone jack in Windows?**

If I want to wear headphones, ideally I'd connect them to my keyboard (short range) and then enable the jack. When I'm done, I'd disconnect my headphones and disable it so my speakers will function as normal.

Comment: Can you set the headphone jack as a seperate out?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that, how do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's suprisingly easy!
Open Volume and you'll see Device name and volume
Next to that Device name you'll see something like (↑) or (↓)
Click on it and you pick the audio source
Easy ;)

Comment: I did notice this way after the fact and forgot to report it. Thanks for the answer!